# does python 'replace' returns wrong error message?

Tags: python, replace

I just coded this:

```
import textract    
text = textract.process('text.pdf')
text = text.replace('\n', '<br>')
print(text)
```

and I got an error because `process` does not return a real `str` object.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "grab.py", line 4, in <module>
    text = text.replace('\n', '<br>')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

But, isn't the error message wrong? Shouldn't it say the reverse like `a str object is required, not bytes` ?

this is python 3.6.9

Comment: I think it's telling you that `text` is a `bytes` object, thus its `replace` function requires `bytes` parameters to match.

Comment: Before the replace line, add `print(type(text))`.  That will tell you exactly what you're looking at.

Comment: @MarkRansom you mean, its complaining about `'\n', '<br>'` because they should be bytes too, when you are using it on a bytes object instead of str?! by the way, `str(text).replace()` works here

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying.  And `str()` will convert a `bytes` object to `str` but it doesn't give you much control, use `bytes.decode()` instead.

Comment: ok you was right, i just tested it with byte attributes, you can post it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `str` and `bytes` objects have a `replace` method.  They differ only in the type of strings they accept as parameters.  In your case it appears that `textract.process` is returning a `bytes` and not a `str`.

```
>>> print(b'123'.replace(b'2', b'X'))
b'1X3'
>>> print('123'.replace('2', 'X'))
1X3
>>> print(b'123'.replace('2', 'X'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    print(b'123'.replace('2', 'X'))
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

You can and should convert your bytes to a proper string.  The way to do this is with `decode`, but you must know the proper encoding or you will get an error or incorrect text.

```
text = text.decode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

`textract` returns a Python `bytes` object, which does have a `replace` method of its own. As seen [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects), `bytes.replace` only accepts "bytes-like" objects. Since you supplied strings instead, it is throwing the correct `TypeError`.

EDIT for clarity:
The replace you're wanting to do regards characters in a string (using `str.replace` instead). To get the desired result make sure to `decode` the object first:

```
import textract    
text = textract.process('text.pdf')
text = text.decode()
text = text.replace('\n', '<br>')
print(text)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but that is not what I asked here for

Comment: @Asara I've edited it to add more information about the error, thanks